# How to write a loop to reflect a path (Asymptote)?

Tags: graphs, loops, asymptote, technical-drawing, for-loop

I am trying to shorten a code that contains a lot of reflections by writing a loop:

```
[asy]
unitsize(1.5 cm);
pair A,B,C;

real alpha=(20);
real beta=(10);
real gamma=(180-alpha-beta);
real rad=(pi/180);

real AC=(3);
real AB=(AC*sin(beta*rad)/sin(gamma*rad));

A=(0,0);
B=(AB*sin(alpha*rad),AB*cos(alpha*rad));
C=(0,AC);
path t=(C--B--A--C);

draw(t);
label("$A$", A,S);
label("$B$", B,W);
label("$C$", C,N);


path reflection1(path t){
t=(reflect(A,B)*t);
draw(t);
pair A=(reflect(A,B)*A);
pair B=(reflect(A,B)*B);
pair C=(reflect(A,B)*C);
return t;
return A;
return B;
return C;}

path reflection2(path t){
path t=(reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(t);
pair A=(reflect(A,C)*A);
pair B=(reflect(A,C)*B);
pair C=(reflect(A,C)*C);
return t;
return A;
return B;
return C;}

path F(path t){
for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
if(i/2==0){
reflection1(t);
}
else{
reflection2(t);
}
}
return t;
}
draw(F(t));

[/asy]
```

I want a graph like this

```
[asy]
unitsize(1.5 cm);
pair A,B,C;

real alpha=(20);
real beta=(10);
real gamma=(180-alpha-beta);
real rad=(pi/180);

real AC=(3);
real AB=(AC*sin(beta*rad)/sin(gamma*rad));

A=(0,0);
B=(AB*sin(alpha*rad),AB*cos(alpha*rad));
C=(0,AC);
path t=(C--B--A--C);
draw(t);
label("$A$", A,S);
label("$B$", B,W);
label("$C$", C,N);


draw(reflect(A,B)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*t);

draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*t);

draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*t);
draw(reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(B,C)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*reflect(A,C)*reflect(A,B)*t);


label("$C_n$",(3,1));
label("$A'$",(6,0),S);
label("$B'$",(5.6,1.5));
label("$C'$",(6,3),N);
label("$A_n$",(3,-2.8));
[/asy]
```

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi!  I see that you have a misconception about how `return` statements work.  If you still need help after you fix this, please edit your question...  When the first `return` statement is reached in a function, the program flow exits the function.  The other `return` statements have no effect.  Also, if you want to modify the global A, B, and C pairs in your function, then use `A=...`, not `pair A=...`.  When you use `pair A=...`, you are defining a new variable scoped to your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to adopt an other strategy by using rotations around the point Cn inside a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
unitsize(1.5 cm);
pair A,B,C;

real alpha=(20);
real beta=(10);
real gamma=(180-alpha-beta);
real rad=(pi/180);

real AC=(3);
real AB=(AC*sin(beta*rad)/sin(gamma*rad));

A=(0,0);
B=(AB*sin(alpha*rad),AB*cos(alpha*rad));
C=(0,AC);

pair C1=reflect(A,B)*C;
pair Cn=rotate(-2*alpha,A)*C1;
pair An=Cn+(0,-AC);

path t1=(C--B--A--cycle);
path t2=reflect(A,B)*t1;
path t3=reflect(A,C1)*t2;
path[] t4={t1,t2,t3};

filldraw(t4^^reflect(An,Cn)*(t4),green);

path[] t5=rotate(-2*alpha,A)*(t2^^t3);
filldraw(t5,blue);

for(int i=1;i<=8;++i){
  filldraw(rotate(i*alpha,Cn)*t5,red);
}

pair[] arrABC={A,B,C};

arrABC=reflect(An,Cn)*arrABC;

label("$A$", A,S);
label("$B$", B,W);
label("$C$",C,N);
label("$C1$", C1,N);
label("$C_n$", Cn,N);
label("$A_n$", An,S);

label("$A'$", arrABC[0],S);
label("$B'$", arrABC[1],W);
label("$C'$", arrABC[2],N);

\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But the reason I choose to rotate from the first triangle is that the graph is not always symmetric.